# Since Haskell is lazily evaluated, why doesn't this code work?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

```
--defining function
safeHead :: [a] -> Maybe a
safeHead [] = Nothing
safeHead (x:_) = Just x

--calling function
safeHead (4:5:3:[]:[])
```

When I call safeHead with the argument (4:5:3:[]:[]) the pattern only evaluates the argument to see if either it is empty or if it has a head. So despite the nonsensical bit "[]:[]" it should not throw an error since this part is not even evaluated.

Comment: Because this is a *type error*. The compiler is *not* lazy, and performs type checks.

Comment: You can not construct a list with two different types in the first place.

Comment: Just in case you've never used a language with compile-time types before: types are *not* tags on values that are computed as the program runs. Types are static restrictions on what values can possibly show up someplace.

Comment: @Redu `4` and `[]` not necessarily have two different types. can have same type.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem is this a *type* error though? `:t safeHead (4:5:3:[]:[])` reports a type, so perhaps not.

Comment: @Will Ness I guess you mean the curious type check `[4,5,6,[]] :: Num [a] => [[a]]`.    It reports a type but you can not even run `id` function on that supposedly list. What is happening there..?

Comment: @Redu: it looks for a `Num` type that is at the same type an item of type `[a]`, but fails to find one (or at least not a straightforward one). The function itself can be defined, but not "used", at least not without introducing non-sensical types and enabling some extensions that are not standard Haskell iirc.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I didn't use any extensions in my answer. (but I did use an outdated GHCi).

Comment: @Redu numeric literals are polymorphic definitions, not values; `4` is actually read as `(fromInteger (4 :: Integer)) :: Num a => a` and so a specific `fromInteger` does its specific job according to the specific type it actually has.

Answer (score 9):

> it should not throw an error since this part is not even evaluated.

The fact that it is not evaluated is irrelevant. Haskell is a statically typed language, and the compiler checks the types. It does not have to calculate the result in order to typecheck the value: the input and output type of all functions are known (well calculated), and the Haskell compiler verifies that type of the output of one function is the same as the input of the function that is called to process that output.

The typechecking is done at *compile time*, and the Haskell compiler is *not* lazy (in the sense that it performs these checks before generating the binary, not just before running the code). The compiler eagerly checks the types and guarantees that the program is sensical from a type system perspective.

For example the following expression will typecheck:

```
1 : 2 : undefined
```

but [**`undefined :: a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:undefined) will raise an error in case it is evaluated.

Haskell allows to define new types of `Num`bers, so you could make a typeclass that parses the numbers `4`, `5` and `3` into numbers of your own type. That type could, strictly speaking be a list.

But Haskell will, if you evaluate this, not find a type to use, and will raise an error:

```
Prelude> safeHead (4:5:3:[]:[])

<interactive>:6:1: error:
    • Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num [t]
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall t. Num [t] => Maybe [t]
```

So here it is looking for a type for the elements of the list, and it finds out that these should be lists, due to the `[]` element (the one but last element), but at the same time these should be `Num`s, now it fails to find such a type, hence the error.

We can strictly speaking construct such a type, such that we can *use* the function in a proper way:

```
Prelude> data A = A deriving Show
Prelude> :{
Prelude| instance Num [A] where
Prelude|     (+) = undefined
Prelude|     (*) = undefined
Prelude|     abs = undefined
Prelude|     fromInteger _ = [A]
Prelude|     negate = undefined
Prelude|     signum = undefined
Prelude| :}
Prelude> :{
Prelude| safeHead :: [a] -> Maybe a
Prelude| safeHead [] = Nothing
Prelude| safeHead (x:_) = Just x
Prelude| :}
Prelude> safeHead (4:5:3:[]:[]) :: Maybe [A]
Just [A]
```

Answer (score 3):

It takes a bit of massaging, but you can sometimes get ghc to *defer* type errors such as this, and give you an answer regardless.

```
-- defer.hs
safeHead :: [a] -> Maybe a
safeHead [] = Nothing
safeHead (x:_) = Just x

n :: Int
n = []

nonsense :: [Int]
nonsense = (4 : 5 : 3 : n : [])

r :: Maybe Int
r = safeHead nonsense
```

Given the above file, if you load this into ghc or ghci using the `-fdefer-type-errors` flag...

```
$ ghci -fdefer-type-errors defer.hs

defer.hs:6:5: warning: [-Wdeferred-type-errors]
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘[a0]’
    • In the expression: []
      In an equation for ‘n’: n = []
  |
6 | n = []
  |     ^^

ghci> r
Just 4

ghci> nonsense !! 3
*** Exception: defer.hs:6:5: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘[a0]’
    • In the expression: []
      In an equation for ‘n’: n = []
(deferred type error)
```

Normally, type errors are *fatal* for Haskell programs, preventing them from being compiled. However *some* such errors can be deferred. This is usually **not** a good idea, and the feature for deferring type errors is somewhat limited in what it can defer.

So to answer your question, Haskell was not designed to let type errors slide, even if said type error does not actually impact any live code path. However, you can sometimes opt in to this dubious behavior, if you so choose.

Answer (score 1):

Every bit in a Haskell program must have a type. *Upfront*.

The term `(4:5:3:[]:[])` actually has a type.

```
> :t safeHead (4:5:3:[]:[])
safeHead (4:5:3:[]:[]) :: Num [t] => Maybe [t]

> safeHead (4:5:3:[]:[])

<interactive>:10:1:
    No instance for (Num [t0]) arising from a use of `it'
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

It's just the instance that is missing.

```
> instance (Num a) => Num [a] where
    a + b = a
    a - b = a
    a * b = a
    abs a = a
    signum a = a
    fromInteger x = [fromInteger x]

> safeHead (4:5:3:[]:[])
Just [4]
it :: Num t => Maybe [t]
```

Numeric literals are polymorphic definitions, not concrete values; `4` is actually read as `(fromInteger 4) :: Num a => a` and so a specific `fromInteger` does its specific job according to the specific type it actually has. Here, it's

```
four :: Num t => Num [t]
four = fromInteger 4         -- according to our definition, it's
     = [fromInteger 4]
```

Turns out it's not a *complete* nonsense after all. :)

Comment: If you *must* use such an instance for list-y numbers, I'd recommend using `Data.ANum` and `Control.Applicative.ZipList` instead.
`ANum (ZipList [1,2,3]) + 1 == ANum (ZipList [2,3,4])`

Comment: I was just reaching for something that works here, after everyone assumed that it doesn't. :) I didn't care whether it does a sensible thing or not. thanks for the reference though, will look into it.

Comment: @DanBurton  lists-of-digits in some base seems like a sensible thing to have a Num instance for.

Comment: I agree that "list-of-digits in some base" could be a sensible thing to have a Num instance for, *if it is newtyped*.
When OP wrote `(4:5:3:[]:[])`, I'm fairly certain they did *not* mean for it to be a list of lists. Better for this to be a type error than for it to silently do something unexpected and bizarre.

Comment: I don't think I advocated nor recommended doing this. If they didn't intend it, they didn't have the instance and indeed got the error. So all is well. For me, a truly bizarre thing to do is the deferring of type errors. :)

Comment: but of course you're right about the newtype, if to have this at all then certainly be explicit about it. I was just concentrating more on what a language can do in general.